# Java composition examples

Tags: java, associations

can anyone tell why the first code works and the second doesn't work, is it because in the second example we didn't create an object of `Monitor` class, and if the first example worked because we created an object then where did we create it?

```
class Pc {
Monitor monitor;

public Pc(Monitor monitor) {
    this.monitor = monitor;
}

void drawLogo() {
    monitor.drawPixelAt();
}

}


class Monitor {
void drawPixelAt() {
    System.out.println("Drawing pixel ");
}

}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pc pc = new Pc(new Monitor());
    pc.drawLogo();
}
}
```

second example

```
class Pc {
Monitor monitor;

void drawLogo() {
    monitor.drawPixelAt();
}

}


class Monitor {
void drawPixelAt() {
    System.out.println("Drawing pixel ");
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pc pc = new Pc();
    pc.drawLogo();
}
}
```

Comment: In the first example you're setting `monitor` in the constructor of `Pc`, and creating an instance of Monitor when calling `new Pc(new Monitor())`, in the second one you're not setting it at all hence the nullpointer you're probably getting.

Comment: Ok @Mark that make sense, but what point to the instance of Monitor.

Comment: With `this.monitor = monitor;` in `Pc(Monitor monitor)` you're setting the variable monitor to the instantiation of `Monitor` in `new Pc(new Monitor())` :)

Comment: aha okay got it, thank a lot @Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monitor needs to be a constructor of your PC, in the first it's there so everything is good, and in the second there isn't a monitor at all. The PC class needs the monitor because it's declared as a constructor.

Like one of the comments said, since nothing is there you'll get a nullpointer exeception.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you are never initializing the "monitor" variable, in the first one you are initializing the "monitor" variable in constructor of PC